# Expressing cartesian unit vectors in terms of plane polar unit vectors to prove that former doesn't depend on position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vectors

I understand that polar unit vectors are given by

$e_r= \cos(θ)i + \sin(θ)j$

$e_θ=−\sin(θ)i + \cos(θ)j$

How do I now express cartesian unit vectors in terms of polar unit vectors to show that they are independent of the $r$ and $θ$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I now express cartesian unit vectors in terms of polar unit vectors to show that they are independent of the $r$ and $θ$?

If you express the cartesian unit vectors in terms of polar unit vectors that means that they are not independent of each other. The unit vectors $i$ and $j$ are independent and so is $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$. But one set is not independent of other.

To find $i$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ by eliminating $j$ from two equation. As follows

$$\cos(\theta)\hat{r}=\cos^2(\theta)\hat{i}+\cos\theta\sin(\theta)\hat{j}$$
$$\sin(\theta)\hat{\theta}=-\sin^2(\theta)\hat{i}+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\hat{j}$$
substracting:

$$\hat{i}=\cos(\theta)\hat{r}-\sin(\theta)\hat{\theta}$$
similear procedure for $\hat{j}$.

---

If you want to show the linear independence of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ then you can show they are perpendicular to each other:
$$\hat{r}\cdot\hat{\theta}=0$$
and for unit vectors $\hat{r}\cdot\hat{r}=1=\hat{\theta}\cdot \hat{\theta}$.

Comment: But i and j remain the same no matter where in the coordinate space the point is, unlike r and  θ. So how is i a function of θ? Shouldn't it be a quantity that is independent of the angle?

Comment: No, because the polar coordinate change from point to point and they should manage to change themselves such that $i$ remain the same. Try changing the value of theta.

Comment: Ah! Makes perfect sense. Thanks!